# What is the weird hand gesture that Kazuma does in season 2 episode 3?

Tags: konosuba

At the end of season 2 episode 3 of *Konosuba*, around 20:47, Kazuma does a weird hand gesture during the celebration where he uses Steal.

I feel I have seen that somewhere else but can't remember.

What does it refer to?

Comment: Could you provide the image, or at least mention which episode/chapter (& timestamp) this happens?

Comment: It happens at the end of episode 3 season 2 during the celebration where he uses steal

Comment: I assume it's the one on 20:47 when he tried to steal the cloth/handkerchief from the guy's hand?

Answer (score 3):

This is a callback to the hand gesture Kazuma made in episode 5 of season 1 (*Kono Maken ni Onedan o!*, or "A Price for This Magic Sword!") when threatening Mitsurugi Kyouya's two hanger-ons with "gender equality".

Kazuma managed to best Kyouya in a duel using underhanded tricks, which prompted insults from Kyouya's two female companions and demands to return the spoils of the match, namely Kyouya's cursed sword Gram. Kazuma's response was as follows (at the timestamp 17:57):

> I'm an advocate of true gender equality — a guy who has no problem doling out a dropkick to a female opponent. Don't think I'll go easy on you. I'll unleash my Steal ability right here in public. *Cue weird hand gesture, indicating he might strip the ladies of their admittedly minimal clothing*.